# Match data in two workbooks and copy a specific cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have two workbooks named main and checker. Each one has single sheets with same names. checker workbook has data stored on H2.

In main workbook, column A has reference numbers. I want when I type reference numbers to column A of checker and click button, code will check if that reference number exists on main sheet's column A, and if it exists, will copy data from checker's H2 to main workbooks column I.

I don't want to paste what I have so far because it is a shame.

Comment: You should always post your code, otherwise we can't help you to improve your code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correct, you need something like this (read comments and put correct data where needed).

```
Sub ChechReferences()
Dim MainSht As Worksheet
Dim CheckSht As Worksheet

Set MainSht = Workbooks("Main_workbook_name").Sheets("Sheet_name") 'Replace Main_workbook_name and Sheet_name with proper names
Set CheckSht = Workbooks("Check_workbook_name").Sheets("Sheet_name") 'Replace Main_workbook_name and Sheet_name with proper names

Dim ReferencesRangeMain As range
Dim ReferencesRangeChecker As range
Dim CellChecker As range
Dim CellMain As range

With MainSht
    Set ReferencesRangeMain = range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With

If ReferencesRangeMain.Rows.Count = 1 Then
    If ReferencesRangeMain.Cells(1, 1) = "" Then Exit Sub
End If

With CheckSht
    Set ReferencesRangeChecker = range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With

If ReferencesRangeChecker.Rows.Count = 1 Then
    If ReferencesRangeChecker.Cells(1, 1) = "" Then Exit Sub
End If


For Each CellChecker In ReferencesRangeChecker
    For Each CellMain In ReferencesRangeMain
        If CellChecker = CellMain Then

            'This is for copying value from column H and row of cell with reference from checker sheet
            'to the column E and row where the reference was found on the main sheet
            'e.g. if you type reference to A5 on a checker sheet, and reference will be found at A8 on
            'the main sheet - then cell H5 on check sheet will be copied to I8 on a main sheet
            CheckSht.Cells(CellChecker.row, 8).Copy Destination:=MainSht.Cells(CellMain.row, 5)

        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Anyway, I think you'll find out how to fix ranges for copying if that is not what you need.